# Making a Zurb Foundation theme for Mezzanine (django-compressor + SASS integration)

Tags: zurb-foundation, mezzanine, django-compressor

I'm building a bilingual site, which has both RTL and LRT content. Mezzanine comes with a twitter-bootstrap theme, which doesn't support RTL as well as zurb-foundation does. So I'm trying to create a new Mezzanine theme that would use foundation for sites.

I'm having trouble structuring my project in a way that django-compressor would understand, with minimal 3rd party dependencies.

The structure that I'd like to emulate is the one in [mezzanine-themes](https://github.com/thecodinghouse/mezzanine-themes/tree/master/flat). However, it is not setup to use SCSS. I've also installed [django-compressor-toolkit](https://github.com/kottenator/django-compressor-toolkit) to deal with SCSS.

The problem now is that I don't know how to structure the static files in the theme app to get compressor to find them.

My hunch is that I have to make compressor-toolkit find the `foundation-sites` file in `node_modules`, but I can't figure how to do that out from reading the docs.

I could put all of the foundation files in the same static folder, but then I lose the nice package management (along with other drawbacks).

Any recommendations?

Many thanks in advance.

---

Below is the error that compressor gives when it reaches the `{% compress css %}` template tag.

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "/Users/majdal/Projects/dar/nimer/static/scss/_settings.scss",
  "line": 63,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: util/util.\nParent style sheet: /Users/majdal/Projects/dar/nimer/static/scss/_settings.scss",
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util.\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/majdal/Projects/dar/nimer/static/scss/_settings.scss\n        on line 63 of nimer/static/scss/_settings.scss\n>> @import 'util/util';\n   ^\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! I had to use `--include-path` for the `node-sass` module.

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'node-sass --scss  --include-path ./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/ --include-path ./node_modules/motion-ui {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```